How to toggle bluetooth on/off from the Windows from the login screen?
I have an bluetooth (BT) security device to allow 2 factor sign-on to a Windows machine.  There is an issue with communication such that sometimes (once a week or so) the device will not connect unless BT is toggled off then on again.  This means I have to login with alternate means and toggle it within Windows.  Much easier would be to cycle BT from the login screen.  Once in Windows, I can use Win + A to quickly toggle BT.  My keyboard does not include a BT button, however the BT is onboard and not a USB dongle.
I have checked the device manager when the device fails to connect and it shows no driver errors.  The device driver is updated per its latest support page.  BT driver is current per Windows update.  Other devices are able to connect and function.
I tried to use the ease of use virtual keyboard, but there is no BT button on it either.  Also Win + A (etc) doesn't seem to function on the login screen.  I googled bluetooth hotkeys but those results are Win + I and Win + A.
Is there a way to toggle BT from the login screen?
